# How can we improve the accuracy of form-recognizer model?

Tags: performance, azure-form-recognizer

I am using Microsoft form-recognizer service. My forms are bit complex and I tried training a model for them. The performance I achieved is not really good. Is there anyway I can improve this accuracy? Is there anyway to tune this model? I have trained the model using 5 different populated forms of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still interested in it. I've been using the [labeling tool in the v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/label-tool) You can manually label area to create tags (features). This can be done without too much effort. I've been using it and get a very accurate results.

IC

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please elaborate your answer including relevant information from the link?